# Hide row in a table when a value appears of a certain column

Tags: mysql

I am using this code

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'nascimento', `first_name`, `last_name`, `name_completo`, `cota`
FROM `socios` 
WHERE MONTH(nascimento) = MONTH(NOW()) 
ORDER BY nascimento ASC"
```

How can I make the code to hide the row when the value "paga" appears on the column 'cota'?

I tried

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'nascimento', `first_name`, `last_name`, `name_completo`, `cota`
FROM `socios` 
WHERE MONTH(nascimento) = MONTH(NOW()) 
ORDER BY nascimento ASCAND cota NOT IN(paga)"
```

but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Your new SQL is clearly broken. You should have gotten an exception here.

Comment: Surely it's just WHERE cota <> 'paga' ?
It should be in the WHERE clause, not the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just put the condition in the wrong place with a wrong syntax too. Anyway check my suggestion:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'nascimento', 
         `first_name`, 
         `last_name`, 
         `name_completo`, 
         `cota` 
FROM     `socios` 
WHERE    MONTH(nascimento) = MONTH(NOW()) AND `cota` != 'paga'
ORDER BY nascimento ASC
```

Comment: I think op might be looking for NOT LIKE